# The Conjugate function of the sum of positive entries

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

If anyone could help me how to find the conjugate of the below function, I would be appreciated. I am a new learner of the convex optimization. How should I approach to problem here? Why the domain of $y$ is restricted to between $0$ and $1$,
especially. Answer is also below.
$$f(x) = 1^T (x)_+,\quad \text{where } (x)_+ = \max \{ 0,x\} $$
Answer:
$$ f(y)^* = 0,\, \text{dom} \ f^* = \{y   \mid  0\preceq y  \preceq 1\} $$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\sup_{x \ge 0} xy -x = \sup_{x \ge 0} x(y-1) = \begin{cases} 0, & y \le 1 \\+\infty, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$, and
$\sup_{x < 0} xy = \begin{cases} +\infty, & y <0 \\0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Combine these to get a formula for $f^*(y)$.

Comment: Thank you, I guess I should have a more deeply understanding of these supremums, but I get it. Thank you!